# What's the difference between "myVar.constructor" and "typeof myVar"?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between...

```
if(myVar.constructor == String)
```

and

```
if(typeof myVar == "string")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `myVar.constructor` just returns the value of the member "constructor".  It's completely possible and legal for a given object to have a constructor which points to string (or anything else).  For example

```
function Apple() {}
var x = new Apple();
x.constructor = String
if (x.constructor == String) {
  // True
}
```

Using the `typeof` operator though provides the information you're looking for

```
if (typeof myVar == 'string') {
  // It's a string
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I have seen both, and in the same script. Surely it makes no sense to ever set the constructor property of an object to something different than it's actual constructor. And the person writing the script clearly knows how to use typeof, so why use x.constructor == String?

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 I'd agree it makes little sense to change the constructor member but that doesn't mean people won't do it :).  I just wanted to make sure you were aware that people could do it.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 myself I'd go the `typeof` route

Comment: so would I. But I'm wondering if there more to this. strings are primitive types and the String reference object is a wrapper for string values. I'm wondering if you were to create an instance of a String object and use typeof on it if it would return Object instead of String?

Comment: Ok so I have checked this out now and it is infact the case! If you create an instance of the String reference type it has a typeof object.   http://jsfiddle.net/FunkyFresh84/JvBSN/

Comment: @JaredPar: `typeof` can be misleading, [correctly] claiming that String instances *(which can totally contain the information you want)* are of type "object". **`.constructor`** is available for String instances and primitives alike. Further elaboration in my community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

### `typeof` can be a little misleading. *Note the following behavior:*

***`typeof`*** *fails on real String instances:*

```
typeof "snub" 
  // "string" -- as expected

typeof new String("snub") 
  // "object" -- even if it's still the string you're after
```

---

***`.constructor`*** *consistently yields the expected result*:

```
"snub".constructor == String 
  // true -- as expected

new String("snub").constructor == String 
  // true -- as expected
```

**All primitive values in JavaScript have a corresponding object wrapper.** It's from where primitives find a prototype chain to inherit from.

Values in JavaScript can be expressed in primitive form (specially inheriting from their respective objects), or directly in object form. It's possible some of your strings are converted into String instances along the way -- by a library perhaps -- and you won't even know it. String objects and primitives generally behave the same way. *Except for with `typeof`, of course.*

**Directly in object form -- even while the inner value may represent something that is a string, number, or otherwise -- `typeof` will respond with `"object"`.**

**`.constructor` is a more reliable way to identify an object's type,** and is directly available to your primitive values *(like all the rest of their inherited functionality)* thanks to a language feature called [*Autoboxing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing).